# MySQL database tables with SMALLINT id fields

Tags: mysql, myisam, sqldatatypes, unsigned-integer

I currently have a few tables in my MySQL database where I declare the `id` field to be of type `SMALLINT(6)` (is this correct as `SMALLINT` only goes to 65535 [length of 5]). I have read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) under integer types that when it is `UNSIGNED` the range increases in the positive to 65535. How will this affect my database if I specifically change the `id` field's attributes to `UNSIGNED`? Also, are there problems when going from `SMALLINT` to `MEDIUMINT`?

My database type is **MyISAM**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine to switch from `SMALLINT` to `MEDIUMINT` - no data will be lost.

A normal integer in MySQL can be any number between a lower limit and an upper limit. With a signed integer, the lower limit is a negative number and the upper is a positive number. A `SMALLINT`, signed, can be between -32768 and 32767. An unsigned integer, however, is only positive. The lower limit is zero, and the upper limit is 65535.

I usually use `INT` for IDs, though. I'd rather have an upper limit to an ID field so high that it should never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with using `UNSIGNED` types is that if you ever do any arithmetic that results in a negative number you end up with a large number instead. However, for ID's this is unlikely to be a problem for and I often use them to reduce memory usage a bit.

I can't think of any problems with using a `SMALLINT` then changing to `MEDIUMINT` because widening a data-type doesn't usually cause issues.